# Advice on Perl map function

Tags: perl, dictionary

I'm having difficulty understanding the behaviour of the map function in the Perl script below

```
my @list = qw/A C T G/;
my @curr = (0, undef, undef, 1);
my @res = map { $list[ $_ ] } @curr;
print @res; #prints AAAC
```

The value of `@res` is `AAAC`. I had expected it be just `AC` as the 2 middle values of `@curr` are `undef`.

My understanding of map is that each item from the list becomes the value of `$_` in turn. So I can understand how `$list[0]` returns A and how `$list[1]` returns C. I can't understand why/how the `undef` values have returned A? To my mind `$list[undef]` would not be a value?

I'm missing something obvious here probably, but would be really grateful for some help

The script  that I take this code from is below. I'm stepping through it in the debugger, and I can see this behaviour in the last line returned by `sub gen_permutate`

```
my @DNA = qw/A C T G/;
my $seq = gen_permutate(14, @DNA);

while ( my $strand = $seq->() ) {
print "$strand\n";

}

sub gen_permutate {
    my ($max, @list) = @_;
    my @curr;
    
    return sub {
        if ( (join '', map { $list[ $_ ] } @curr) eq $list[ -1 ] x @curr ) {
            @curr = (0) x (@curr + 1);
        else {
            my $pos = @curr; 
            while ( --$pos > -1 ) {
                ++$curr[ $pos ], last if $curr[ $pos ] < $#list; 
                $curr[ $pos ] = 0;
            }
        }
        return undef if @curr > $max;
        return join '', map { $list[ $_ ] } @curr; 
    };
}
```

J

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent. It would have revealed why you got `AAAC`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a part of "DWIM" -- an array index need be a number, so what is passed in is converted to one, as best as the interpreter can do/guess.  In case of `undef` at least it's clear -- becomes a `0`.

But it's really a programming error, or at least sloppiness.

To do what you expect:

```
my @res = map { $list[ $_ ] } grep { defined } @curr;
```

or, in one iteration over the list

```
my @res = map { defined $_ ? $list[$_] : () } @curr;
```

Here the empty list, indicated by `()`, gets flattened into the return list, thus disappearing; so we filter inside `map` as well.  But the point of that ternary is to be able to put something meaningful instead, and if some input need be just removed then having an explicit `grep` first is clearer.

**NOTE**   With `use warnings;` in place you'd hear all about it

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in array element at ...

(and it would convert it to a number)

Each script really *must* begin with `use warnings;` (and `use strict;`). Sometimes the biggest part in inheriting older scripts is to stick `use warnings;` on top right away (and work through the screenfulls of messages :(.

Answer (score 0):

I think to answer my own question, that undef is sometimes treated as zero. That is why $list[undef] is the same as $list[0]

Comment: undef is a valid scalar, a variable that is undef in a numerical operation/context, it pretends to be 0 and in a string operation/context, it pretends to be the empty string. As @zdim mentioned If warnings are enabled, program will warn message

Comment: Put more simply, when you treat undef as a number, you get a warning (if enabled) and 0 is used (instead of killing your program).